# Getting 'NSInvalidArgumentException' error while using 'endEditing'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error:

[Clima.WeatherViewController searchPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f996b204020
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Clima.WeatherViewController searchPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f996b204020'

Here is my code:

```
IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField! 
IBAction func searchedButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) { 
         searchField.endEditing(true);
         print(searchField.text!) 
}
```

Comment: IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!
IBAction func searchedButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        searchField.endEditing(true);
        print(searchField.text!)   
    }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. It looks pretty obvious from the error message. Your code is calling `searchPressed` on a view controller that does not have a `searchPressed` function.

Comment: Select your button and look at the `Connections Inspector` pane. I'm guessing your button has a connection to `searchPressed` but your renamed the function in your code to `searchedButtonPressed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to disconnect you IBAction of your button & reconnect it. Because it seems that you had changed your IBAction function name after connect it. So your story board still has connection with old name **search Pressed**. & You already renamed it into **searchedButtonPressed** so your story board can not find this new name.

**For disconnect your IBAction method:**

right click on search button in story board & you will see connections you made in manu, close the connection with little colse button placed on top of the corner with the name **searchPressed**.

**For reconnect your IBAction method:**

Ctrl press on the keyboard & dreg on the search button to the small circle you will see beside your IBAction method.